# How to configure IdentitiesOnly for github?

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

At the end of my `~/.ssh/config` file I like to define

```
Host *
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Now I had the issue that I wanted to add an entry for the github ssh key like

```
Host github
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github

 
Host *
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

But this resulted in an authentication failure. If I removed the `Host *...` it worked fine again, so I figure the `IdentitiesOnly` fallback (under `Host *`) must have caused that. To alleviate this, I added the `IdentitiesOnly no` to the `github` entry, but this still resulted in an authentication failure.

```
Host github
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
  IdentitiesOnly no

 
Host *
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

As far as I understand this should have worked as according to the manual the *first* applicable definition of a property should hold, but here it doesn't seem to be the case. I assume I'm misunderstanding something else. Can anyone point out what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you uploaded `~/.ssh/github.pub` to your account at GitHub? Do you use `github` and not `github.com` as the host? Can you pleas [edit] and show us formatted text output for `ssh -Tv git@github` with and without `IdentitiesOnly no`?

Comment: @phd Thanks, yes the public key is on github (as I said it works fine without the `Host *` part) - I'll add the output as soon as I'm working on that machine again.